# Automatically close the Form window after submitting

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form **as an iframe in a Google Sheet**.

I need to **close the form automatically after submitting answers**.

Ideal scene would be:

**a person hits submit button, the answers have been recorded and the window 
    closes automatically.**

But there is a following window ("thank you for you response" window) which (from my experience) is probably not possible to disconnect from the form and not to lose answers.

In this case it would be good to **automatically close this second window right after it appears**.

p.s. For submitting the form I use
 `<button type="SUBMIT">Submit</button>`
(I copied and pasted, then modified the html because the form didn't work properly in an iframe mode)

Comment: How are you using `<button type="SUBMIT">Submit</button>` to submit a Google Form?

Comment: Here's how: in an iframe mode the form didn't work properly (submit button were not submitting, input lines were not active). I had to insert my own button and edit the html.

Comment: I need to implement auto closing the form but I haven't found a solution that would work yet. I am learning so possibly made some mistakes.

Comment: You're not providing enough information.  A Google Form isn't designed to have it's html edited.  Unless you are using a regular html form, and calling it a Google Form?  If you are trying to "hack" a Google Form, then I'm not sure that the time and effort to do that is worth it.  You can create an Apps Script Web App with an input form, and embed the Web App into an iframe.  That would require work, but what you're doing now is requiring time and effort also.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will learn web apps for sure. Here I copy and pasted the html code from the form.

Comment: Okay. It's very difficult to work with the copied html from the Google Form.  I don't know anyone who has successfully been able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully handled all issues by implementing elements from Materialize framework into my dialog withing a Spreadsheet.

Amazing look and functionality!

For the dialog I used  `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog()`.

Thank you for your answers and reactions which made me search for better options and discover such amazing solutions for myself.